# Getting unorginized json attribute order from wso2 dataservice

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server

I was about creating an API using WSO2 Dataservice but i'm getting unorginized json attribute order from wso2 dataservice .
Below my dataservice configuration :

```html
       <query id="consultationCommande" useConfig="mscrm">
    <sql><![CDATA[select ordernumber ****** :filterQuery ]]></sql>
    <result outputType="json">{
     "accounts":  
              { "account" :
[{
"codeClient":"$new_codeClient",
"refCompteFacturation": "$new_comptedefacturationidName",
"refCommande": "$refCommande",
 "canalEntree": "$canalEntree",
 "typeCommande": "$typedecontrat",
 "prepaye": "$prepaye",
 "refContrat": "$refContrat",
 "codeOffre": "$refOffre",
 "refContratBoutique": "$new_referencecontratboutique",
 "origineContrat": "$origineContrat",
 "libelleOrigine": "$new_revendeurIdName",
 "dateDebut": "$new_datedebutducontrat" ,
 "dateFin": "$new_datefinducontrat"
}]
}
}</result>
<param name="filterQuery" sqlType="QUERY_STRING"/>
  </query>
```

Below the output of the API call :

```
{
    "accounts": {
        "account": [
            {
                "canalEntree": "Agence",
                "refContratBoutique": null,
                "origineContrat": "Agence",
                "prepaye": "Non",
                "refCommande": "********",
                "refCompteFacturation": "P-2014-060277-003",
                "codeClient": "P-2014-060277",
                "libelleOrigine": null,
                "dateDebut": "2017-07-03T12:12:00.000+01:00",
                "dateFin": "2018-07-03T12:12:00.000+01:00",
                "refContrat": "20170703-1370699-H31C85",
                "typeCommande": "Abonnement",
                "codeOffre": "********"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there any solution to fix this issue.